# how to get date from datepicker to another activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm very new to Android Studio and I am building a simple countdown timer app. I have 2 activities. The first activity(Login) the user picks a date through date picker, the second activity(Profile) shows a countdown timer. The countdown timer works perfectly when I set a date for it in the java class, but i'm having trouble trying to retrieve the date from the login activity. My code for both activities is below.

I know I have to alter the Date futureDate = dateFormat.parse("2016-8-10"); but I'm not sure how.

LOGIN.CLASS

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, OnClickListener {
//private SharedPreferences sp;

EditText enterusername;
Button continuetoprofile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    /*sp = getSharedPreferences("myPreference" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("myKey" , "I am data to store");
    editor.commit();

     Writing data to SharedPreferences*/

    enterusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterusername);
    continuetoprofile=(Button) findViewById(R.id.continuetoprofile);
    continuetoprofile.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//SHARED PREFERENCES
/*public void saveInfo(View view){
    SharedPreferences save = getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = save.edit();
    editor.putString("username",enterusername.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
}*/



public void onClick (View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Profile.class);
    intent.putExtra("username", enterusername.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void datePicker(View view){

    DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date");
}
private void setDate(final Calendar calendar) {
    final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.showDate)).setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
    setDate(cal);
}
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)
                        getActivity(), year, month, day);
    }

}
Intent intent = getIntent();
public void privPol(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PrivacyPolicy.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void TOU(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TermsOfUse.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void toProfile(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

PROFILE.CLASS

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
//private SharedPreferences spref;
//TextView nameofuser;

TextView nameofuser;
private TextView daystxt, hourstxt, minutestxt, secondstxt;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    initUI();
    countDownStart();

    nameofuser = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameofuser);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
    nameofuser.setText("Welcome,  " + username);

}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private void initUI() {
    daystxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days);
    hourstxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hours);
    minutestxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
    secondstxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
}
public void countDownStart() {
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                // Here Set your Event Date
                Date futureDate = dateFormat.("2016-8-10");
                Date currentDate = new Date();
                if (!currentDate.after(futureDate)) {
                    long diff = futureDate.getTime()
                            - currentDate.getTime();
                    long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    diff -= days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                    diff -= hours * (60 * 60 * 1000);
                    long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
                    diff -= minutes * (60 * 1000);
                    long seconds = diff / 1000;
                    daystxt.setText("" + String.format("%02d", days));
                    hourstxt.setText("" + String.format("%02d", hours));
                    minutestxt.setText("" + String.format("%02d", minutes));
                    secondstxt.setText("" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                } else {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    // handler.removeMessages(0);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
}

Intent intent = getIntent();
public void toMenu(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void tostartdate(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditStartdate.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What have you done to try to figure out the problem? Have you tried to step through the code to see what value is being returned? Are you getting exceptions?

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet I've tried using intent the same way i used to to retrieve the string name, but that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Get the date 
Date buttonDate = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().parse(mDate.getText().toString());
```

and

```
  //Create a bundle to pass the date and send your date as Long
            Bundle currentDate = new Bundle();
            currentDate.putLong("setDate", buttonDate.getTime());
```

and

```
 //Read the passed bundle from the next activity get Long and convert it to Date 
Bundle setDate = this.getArguments();
Long currDate = setDate.getLong("setDate");
```

Note :
The Date constructor accepts the time as long in milliseconds, not seconds. You need to multiply it by 1000 and make sure that you supply it as long.

conversion

```
Date d = new Date(1220227200L * 1000);
```

Comment: would I put this all in my second activity? How would I retrieve the date from my Login activity?

Comment: get you date and prepare bundle and send it from your first activity and get the bundle from second activity and convert it back to a Date type again

Answer (score 0):

Try using the putExtras() method to pass it through the Intent in a Bundle.

The following code will help out:

**Sending Data through Bundle**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putExtras("Date",YOUR_DATE);

i.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(i);
```

**Getting Data in new Activity**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

String date = bundle.getString(“Date”);
```

This will help